# Account Redirect page for EDIT is working for VF pages but for standard layouts its malfunctioning

Tags: visualforce, redirect

The below Account Redirect page for EDIT is working fine for VF pages but for standard layouts after editing the record it is not returning home page instead of account detail page.

Am i missing something here?

```
public with sharing class DispatcherAccounteditController {
public DispatcherAccounteditController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public PageReference getRedir() {
Account acc = [Select id, recordtypeid From Account Where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

        PageReference newPage;

        if (acc.recordtypeid == '0123B000000Hs88') {
            newPage = Page.AccountEdt;
        } else {
            newPage = new PageReference('/' + acc.id +'/e');
            newPage.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');     
        }
             newPage.getParameters().put('id', acc.id);

             return newPage.setRedirect(true);

    }

    private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `retURL` in Url parameters. So your code would be like:

```
public with sharing class DispatcherAccounteditController {
   public DispatcherAccounteditController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
      this.controller = controller;
   }

   public PageReference getRedir() {
      Account acc = [Select id, recordtypeid From Account Where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

      PageReference newPage;

     if (acc.recordtypeid == '0123B000000Hs88') {
        newPage = Page.AccountEdt;
     } else {
        newPage = new PageReference('/' + acc.id +'/e');
        newPage.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');

 newPage.getParameters().put('retURL', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
     }
        newPage.getParameters().put('id', acc.id);

        return newPage.setRedirect(true);

}

private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
}
```

Comment: That worked...Thanks much.

Comment: Please mark it reslove.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting id parameter twice in URL when recordtypeid is not matching with the mentioned one, i.e. when else is executed. Try after moving `newPage.getParameters().put('id', acc.id);` code block  in IF part.

Comment: Hi Ashish, the issue i am facing is, if the detail page is a vf page, then after an adit made to the record it is perfectly redirecting to the vf detail page. However if the detail page is standard layout then then after editing the record it is redirecting to home page instead of the standard record detail page.